# Array in Winsock Async

Tags: c#, winsock

I'm trying to create an array for each person who connect to the server.

The connection works , however, when the server receives information , I have no way of knowing who was who sent this information.

How do I know who is the index of the list " clients" who sent the information ?

Look the code:

Basic definitions

```
public string Ip { get; set; }
public Socket Ansyc { get; set; }
public int Index { get; set; }
public int Id { get; set; }
public UserConnection(Socket t, int i) { Ansyc = t; Id = i; }
```

Winsock

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ACESERVER
{
    // State object for reading client data asynchronously
public class StateObject {
    // Client  socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
}
    class WinsockAnsyc
    {
    //clients
    public static List<UserConnection> Clients = new List<UserConnection>(100);
    // Thread signal.
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);


    public static void StartListening() {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        // The DNS name of the computer
        // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Any;
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 5000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        try {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true) {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                Console.WriteLine("Aguardando conexão...");
                listener.BeginAccept( 
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener );

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {

        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set();

        // Socket \o/.
        Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        //Adicionamos ele na lista
        Clients.Add(new UserConnection(handler, Clients.Count()));
        //Vamos analisar qual index está disponível para o jogador

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)     
        {    
            if (UserConnection.CheckIndex(i))   
            {  
                WinsockAnsyc.Clients[(Clients.Count() - 1)].Index = i;
                break;   
            }     
        }


        //Zerar o Player_HighIndex pra evitar problemas

        Globals.Player_HighIndex = 0;


        //Vamos atualizar o Player_HighIndex sem frescura

        for (int i = 0; i < Clients.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (WinsockAnsyc.Clients[i].Index > Globals.Player_HighIndex)
            {
                Globals.Player_HighIndex = WinsockAnsyc.Clients[i].Index; 
            }
        }

        //Vamos atualizar o Player_HighIndex para todos os jogadores
        SendData.Send_UpdatePlayerHighIndex();

        //WinsockAnsyc.Clients[Clients.Count() - 1].ListIndex = Clients.Count() - 1;
        Listen.Log(String.Format("Cliente conectado: {0}", Clients.Count() - 1));

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = Clients[Clients.Count - 1].Ansyc;
        Clients[Clients.Count - 1].Ansyc.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }


    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        String content = String.Empty;
        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;
        handler.

        // Clients[Clients.Count - 1].Ansyc.EndReceive(ar)
        // Read data from the client socket. 
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                state.buffer,0,bytesRead));
            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
            // more data.
            content = state.sb.ToString();
            Server.Network.ReceiveData.SelectPacket(client.Index, content);
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1) {
                // All the data has been read from the 
                // client. Display it on the console.
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                    content.Length, content );
                // Echo the data back to the client.
                Send(handler, content);
            } else {
                // Not all data received. Get more.
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data) {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        try {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Anyone haves tips or a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your `StateObject` class should contain all the necessary context you need to identify the client. You should not generally even need to consult the list of clients to handle a single client's individual I/O operation, since that `StateObject` should be enough.

Without [a more complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I can't be more specific than that.

Comment: I need to know who is: WinsockAnsyc.Clients[i].Index when receive a data.

Comment: @user3571412: You're not being clear. What does "who is index" even mean? Are you saying you need to know the value of `i` in the expression `WinsockAnsyc.Clients[i].Index`? Regardless, like I wrote, your `StateObject` class should contain all the information you need when processing an I/O operation. If it doesn't have that information now, just add it. Then you'll have it.

Comment: @user3571412: You'd have to post a minimal, complete code example for anyone to be able to tell you how exactly to add it. Emphasis on both **minimal** _and_ **complete**. See the link I provided in my answer for information about why and how to do that.